# Snap SVG sequential animation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I want to animate a square sequentially, first a 90 degree clockwise rotation and then a simple x axis translation. Here is the Javascript code I have using Snap svg

```
r.animate({ transform: 'r90, 100, 200' }, 1000, mina.easein, function() {     
    r.animate( {transform: 't 100 0'}, 1000, mina.easein );
  }
);
```

Code pen can be found here: https://codepen.io/gauravsingh_/pen/xOVGar

The rotation goes as expected, however the translation is problematic and unexpected.

Can someone please take a look and describe what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that transforms aren't cumulative, so you need to express the full transform each time.

So for the 2nd callback transform you would need this inside...

```
 r.animate( {transform: 't 100 0r90,100,200'}, 1000, mina.easein );
```

Raphael used to allow relative transforms with t vs T, but this isn't the case in Snap.

So if you leave out the r90,100,200 it will assume you want to rotate back to 0, as that is no longer set. Note, it's a bit more complicated than that, as behind the scenes Snap will use Matrices, but it's probably the best way to think of it.

So build up your transform string with your translations, rotation, scaling as you go for any subsequent animations.